# Python how to check if a thread has already started

Tags: python, multithreading, join

I have a list of threads in my Python application. An additional thread is managing all these threads and sometimes it calls `thread.join()` on the other threads. The problem is that some of these threads might not have been started yet. This leads to the error:

```
RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
```

How can I check if a thread has been started, before calling the `join()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the event `thread._started` should do the trick. So `thread._started.is_set()` returns true if the thread has been started.